# I've set the button to disable after the particular function but it does not execute when I click on im butron

Tags: javascript

I got multiple buttons and after a particular function is run, I wanted the div element to be set disabled until the page is reloaded. I tried making the button disable too but that didn't work either

```
 <div class='container'>
        <div  class = 'btn' id = 'rock'>
            <button ><img src="./images/rock-svgrepo-com.svg"></button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'btn' id = 'paper'>
            <button > <img src="./images/paper-plane-svgrepo-com.svg"></button>
        </div>

        <div class= 'btn'  id = 'scissors'>
            <button> <img src="./images/scissors-svgrepo-com.svg"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have used the specific javascript to disable the div

```
function endGame(){
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
    buttons.disabled = true;
    console.log(buttons);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Return types matter.

[`const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList of `div` elements, and not a single button.

So instead, you have to iterate over the list and [disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) each button.

As in

```js
// Select every *button* element inside the container
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.container button');

// Set the disabled attribute. 
// Note that only form elements, like buttons, can be disabled
buttons.forEach(button => button.disabled = true);
```

Comment: i tried that too but the function keeps running on the button  only, but not the img tag which is inside of the button.

Comment: That's because you can't disable arbitrary divs, instead you have to disable the actual button elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Lemme edit my answer.

Comment: I did iterate over each button and they are disabled after certain function and its working as i intended it to,  but the <img> tag inside of the <button> element executes the function and I do understand that the disable works on the button element only , do u know some other way to work around it

Answer (score 0):

Using removeEventListener fixed by terminating the function from running, Thank you though!

```
function endGame(){
    
       
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
         // iterating through each button element 
        buttons.forEach(button => {
          button.removeEventListener('click', playRound); // removes the orginal eventListener by matching the event and the function.
          button.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            
          });
        };
```